# mariadb FOUNDS_ROWS() is not working

Tags: java, mariadb, mybatis

I`m using mariadb-10.1.16.

FOUND_ROWS is always well working in HeidiSQL.

But, When I use mybatis in java, Sometimes FOUND_ROWS() returns 0 value.

I don`t know what problem is.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's see the statement before it, the one where you have `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.  And be sure that there are no intervening queries.

Now I am going to go out on a limb...

1. Turn on the "general log" until you the "0 value" happens.
2. Turn off the general log (to avoid filling up disk)
3. Find the two `SELECTs` in the log.
4. Find what is between them.  Then file a bug with mybatis saying that the extra statements wrecked your code.